# enable diagnostic for Azure subscription using powershell cmdlet

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, scom

Is it really possible to enable diagnostic for entire Azure subscrition using powershell cmdlet? or diagnostics should be enabled case by case(monitoring azure application,monitoring vm and storage account)?

in the operations manager console,we added our azure subscription,imported azure management pack but the Operations manager does not discover the azure cloud service,vm or storage account under that subscrption...we hope that enabling diagnostic for the azure subscription will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as

> Enabling diagnostics for the azure subscription

Even more, there is no diagnostics for VM (Azure VM) or Azure Storage. The only diagnostics you can enable is for a [Cloud Service](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/). You can [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433048.aspx).

For your [Windows Azure Virtual Machines](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) (not a cloud service) you have to manage diagnostics/monitoring the way you do on-premises. There is nothing specific to Azure, nor there is a `special` azure diagnostics for Virtual Machines.

[Storage accounts](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/storage/) can only be monitored via [Storage Analytics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343270.aspx) which again are configured on `per-storage-account` basis and not on subscription level.